# After Todd Rider's thesis, why are companies still working on aneutronic and non-equilibrium fusion?

Tags: energy, fusion

Todd Rider's thesis (*[Fundamental limitations on plasma fusion systems not in thermodynamic equilibrium](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/11412)*) clearly states in the abstract that:

> ...In virtually all cases, [the] minimum recirculating power is substantially larger than fusion power, so barring the discovery of methods for recirculating power at exceedingly high efficiencies, reactors employing plasmas not in thermodynamic equilibrium will not be able to produce net power. Consequently, the advanced aneutronic fuels cannot generate net power in any foreseeable reactor operating either in or out of equilibrium...

I cannot seem to find anything that proves this wrong, only a whole lot of support for it. His arguments are widely cited as reasons why IEC devices like fusors or reactors like migma fail. However, just a simple web search will find companies that claim to have the technology for net power producing aneutronic fusion. For example, there's [TAE technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAE_Technologies), which claims to have the technology to produce power from proton-boron-11 fusion for relatively long (millisecond timescale). That's just one example – there are plenty of others.

This seems to be in direct contradiction to Rider's thesis. So has he been proved wrong? Or are they relying on the fact that his conclusions have never been experimentally verified and assuming he's wrong? Or is there some loophole in his argument that I can't see?

I.e., does this mean that *power generating* aneutronic fusion and/or non-equilibrium fusion is possible with current technology?

Comment: I mean, theory and experiment have never been found in contradiction...

Comment: The abstract of this article 1997, probably extracted from the thesis you are quoting, says basically the same thing: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.872556 . You can find the papers that cite this 1997 article here: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1997PhPl....4.1039R/citations ...maybe you can find your answer in some of those, more recent, papers that cite it.

Comment: @Quillo - I looked in the first five, and every one agrees with Rider's concerns. 6 might be read to suggest otherwise, but does not do so in depth. I could not find any hint of anyone suggesting the concerns are not correct.

Comment: Would larger reactors than assumed by Rider tip the balance back in favor of aneutronic reactions being net-productive ? Also, here are some recent peer-reviewed research papers from TAE (maybe they contain some hint): https://tae.com/research-library/

Comment: As far as I can tell, larger reactors become more effective only with neutronic reactions because you can decrease the surface area/volume ratio -- I.e, neutrons will be more likely to transfer their energy back into the plasma. Since aneutronic reactors can keep everything confined, AFAIK size doesn't matter. In thermal reactors, only a few ions on the Boltzmann curve can actually fuse. For high energy aneutronic reactions, bremsstrahlung exceeds fusion power because most ions are too slow. The only way is non-thermal and if Todd Rider's thesis bars it, *aneutronic fusion will never happen.*

Comment: From the citations that @Quillo mentioned, [this one](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015JPlPh..81a9007P/abstract) may be of interest. That paper restates Rider's thesis and points out that Rider uses a restrictive case (where the beam energy is centered around a single value). The paper's approach uses a non-thermal distribution that is more flat than a Boltzmann distribution, but lacks a high-energy peak that Rider's thesis assumes. The abstract of Rider's thesis may be a bit broad for what it says, but I don't have the skill to confirm/deny this.

Comment: Consider how many orders of magnitude [fusion records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#Records) [have improved](https://twitter.com/arthurturrell/status/1421894438968860674). To compare research aspirations to Rider's constraints, we need more quantitative language than "in _virtually_ all cases... _substantially_ larger... _exceedingly_ high... _advanced_ aneutronic... _a certain_ level". But as even his chapter summaries don't address this, you may have to read the thesis in full.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm an inveterate fusion skeptic, so take this with a grain of salt, but here goes:

"why are companies still working on aneutronic and non-equilbrium fusion?"

Because people give them money in spite of any impossibility in their physics. So why not? And the people investing in these see it as pure hail-mary with their funny money. So again, why not?

No, I don't think these are (all) scams, but I do think they are very much in the realm of pathological science. They really believe they are going to save the world and no amount of reality will convince them otherwise. If removing the prism didn't convince Blondlot that [N-rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ray) didn't exist, what do you think it takes to convince someone who's saving the entire planet?

I won't relate the story here, but I have talked to someone who produced a report about one particular scheme and why it could not possibly work (unrelated to Rider's issue). Twenty-five years later, people continue to give the company millions upon millions of dollars. As far as he is aware, not one person has ever followed up on this report while doing due diligence.

If they don't care about *that*, why would they possibly care about some theoretical problem that's got a lot of math like Rider's paper when the guys that are gushing about their concept are saying it doesn't apply [because reasons]?

Comment: Would larger reactors than assumed by Rider tip the balance back in favor of aneutronic reactions being net-productive ?

Comment: Rider's work shows that it is the radiative limit that is the issue, not the ion confinement time, which is what a larger reactor gets you. A larger volume would help if the plasma was opaque at x-rays, but even in ICF this is basically zero. It's not the same in thermalized systems using D-T because they operate much further from the radiative limit so particle confinement is an attackable issue.

Comment: Larger radius would reduce synchrotron radiation, but it looks like the main loss issue is brems radiation from thermally induced collisions. In this case, wouldn't a larger reactor help anyway because it could run cooler ?

Comment: I'm not sure how the later follows from the first. Why would this allow it to run cooler? You still need to overcome the column barrier and that defines your lower bound.

Comment: I thought that they allow longer confinement time, thus for same Lawson triple product, can use lower temperature. But from what I just gathered at wiki, "confinement time" is just another expression for 1/losses. And for aneutronic fusion, the losses aren't reduced (because bremsstrahlung anyway exits the reactor). Therefore, "confinement time" does not increase in a larger reactor for aneutronic fusion. Is that correct ?

Comment: Ahhh, yes that is it. There's multiple inputs to confinement time. In a thermalized reactor, the radiative losses are minimized and a major loss mechanism is the fuel doing a random walk out of the confinement area, taking its energy with it. Making a larger reactor means it has to move further and thus increases total confinement. Rider's point was that in non-thermal fuels the radiative losses are enormous, so the particle loss mechanism becomes unimportant. So a larger reactor doesn't help, the radiation is a total loss.